# face-attribute function returning strange cons with "quote", causing htmlfontify-buffer bug: 'invalid face: quote'

Tags: quote, htmlfontify

I've been debugging an error when I call `htmlfontify-buffer` on my `*shell*` buffer or SLIME.

I found out the problem seems to be a value returned by the `face-attribute` function that seems to be a `cons` whose first element is just `quote`. That gets passed to the `hfy-face-to-style-i` function which then breaks with error `invalid face: quote`.

Here's a demonstration of the problematic value:

```
(face-attribute 'ansi-color-bold :inherit)
'bold

(type-of (face-attribute 'ansi-color-bold :inherit))
cons

(princ (face-attribute 'ansi-color-bold :inherit))
'bold'bold

(car (face-attribute 'ansi-color-bold :inherit))
quote
```

I don't understand enough elisp to know if this is "ok" and the bug is in the other parts of the code.

Looking with the debugger, I see that this weird value comes into play when `hfy-face-attr-for-class` is called with the `FACE` argument with value `'ansi-color-bold`...

In the Customization buffer, I see that this face has a List Expression:

```
((t
  (:inherit 'bold)))
```

When FACE gets passed into `(face-attr-construct face)`, it returns `(:inherit 'bold)`.

This gets into `hfy-face-to-style-i` as `fn` which does:

```
    (let ((key  (car  fn))
          (val  (cadr fn))
```

Now, `val` has the weird value, it runs this:

```
      (if (eq key :inherit)
        (let ((vs (if (listp val) val (list val))))
```

As `listp val` returns `t`, as the weird value is a `cons`, now `vs` has the value `'bold` and it goes on to `dolist` on it:

```
          (dolist (v vs)
            (setq parent
                  (append
                   parent
                   (hfy-face-to-style-i
                    (hfy-face-attr-for-class v hfy-display-class))))))
```

In the first iteration, `v` is just `quote`. `(type-of v)` returns `symbol`.

And that's how `quote` gets passed to `hfy-face-to-style-i` which errors out.

So, I belive I have all information to know how to fix the bug, but still can't do it as I fail to understand this one weird `cons` with `quote` and symbol `bold` in it.

Is that a "proper" value? If so, should I edit the `dolist` call above to handle the `quote` specially? Or do I need to fix this value being returned by `face-attribute` in the first place?

EDIT:

I found out that `ansi-color-bold` is defined like this at `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/ansi-color.el.gz`:

```
(defface ansi-color-bold
  '((t :inherit 'bold))
  "Face used to render bold text."
  :group 'ansi-colors
  :version "28.1")
```

Is the `'bold` incorrectly quoted as @db48x says? I found [this file](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/ansi-color.el#L93) on GitHub here but it does not seem to have a quote... This file seems to be part of my installation, which came from brew.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo in your customization of the `ansi-color-bold` face. Remove the apostrophe and the problem will go away.

The apostrophe tells the Lisp interpreter to quote the next thing that it reads, so `'(+ 2 2)` evaluates to the list of three things, a symbol `+` and two `2`s while `(+ 2 2)` evaluates to `4` (because it is a call to the addition function).

Internally this quoting is done by consing the value with the symbol `quote`. Thus `'(+ 2 2)` is read as `(quote (+ 2 2))` and `'bold` is read as `(quote bold)`.

Your problem happens when you use a quote inside of something that is already quoted. Something like `'(+ 2 'bold)` is read as `(quote (+ 2 (quote bold)))` (this is a nonsense expression, but it is illustrative).

Comment: @renato You can check the definition added by the customization at the end of your init file. Maybe in the customization buffer, you could just 'Erase the customization' for the face via the 'Revert' button at the top.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I do not customize anything. The  ansi-color-bold config shows as "STANDARD" in the apropos view. I searched anyway on my custom file and ther's no reference to "bold" anywhere.

Comment: Edited the question to mention that I found the definition of `ansi-color-bold` and it does have a double-quote, but I can't change that even by calling `eval-last-sexp`. Seems to be a bug in my distro?

Comment: I fixed the problem now by replacing my distribution's `ansi-color.el.gz` file (which had several other fonts with the extra quote breaking stuff) with the one I found on GitHub (had to remove the .elc file). Thanks for the hint.

Comment: A quick check of the history of that file shows that this bug was [fixed a little over a year ago](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/96f58718a043bb50408592aa1975721396de274e). Maybe you should just upgrade?

Comment: I have this same bug on my other laptop, where I installed emacs a couple of weeks ago only... I suppose "brew" is what needs to upgrade?

Comment: I am on the latest emacs available on brew, which is `28.2 (9.0)`. They seem to use https://emacsformacosx.com/, I will try to report a bug there.